# Overwriting file in c# using stream writer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a html file using stream writer in c#, it is overwriting the file if close the application and run again, but its appending when I tried to write file for different scenario  without closing the application. I wants to overwrite in second case also.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Report.html", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))                 
{
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
    {                               
        w.WriteLine(html); 
    }
}
```

Comment: FileMode.Create causes an existing file to be overwritten, not appended to.  You should show the code thats causing the append. (Also ensure your not appending to `html`)

Answer (score 0):

To append to the end of your file:

```
File.AppendAllText("Report.html", html, Encoding.UTF8);
```

To overwrite your file:

```
File.WriteAllText("Report.html", html, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try explicitly closing the writer and stream instead of depending upon you using () expression to do that for you.

Comment: `using` is unreliable?

Comment: No but he didn't show the code where it is appending, and I suspect it's appending because he's trying to use the stream repeatedly within the same using expression. Using expressions work great so long as you understand the implications.